# How can I condition a constraint on the value of an array?

Tags: optimization, conditional-statements, julia, julia-jump

I have this condition and I would like to know how can I condition it to be created only when S = constant, otherwise it is not created. I want it to be within the range 1:B.
This is the constraint:

```
@constraint(model, pf[j=1:B], 
            sum(P[j]*A[i] * y[i,j] * f[j] for i in 1:GX)) >= f[j] * L[j] * phi
```

and I wanted to condition to something like S != 'constant' where constant can be a customizable value. For example, if S = 0.01 the constraint is created, otherwise it's not.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Is the answer by Oscar what you were looking for or do you need `S` to be a decision variable inside the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular Julia control flow:

```
if S == 0.01
    @constraint(
        model,
        pf[j=1:B], 
        sum(P[j]*A[i] * y[i,j] * f[j] for i in 1:GX) >= f[j] * L[j] * phi,
    )
end
```

If this doesn't answer the question, please post it on the JuMP community forum https://jump.dev/forum and provide some more information.

Comment: Thank You! I did this and it worked fine: @constraint(
        model,
        pf[j in B; S == 0.1], 
        sum(P[j]*A[i] * y[i,j] * f[j] for i in 1:GX) >= f[j] * L[j] * phi)

Comment: Yes, that's effectively the same condition.